# Run ssh and immediately execute command

Tags: bash, unix, ssh

I'm trying to find UNIX or bash command to run a command after connecting to an ssh server.  For example:

```
ssh name@ip "tmux list-sessions"
```

The above code works, it lists the sessions, but it then immediately disconnects.  Putting it in the sshrc on the server side works, but I need to be able to type it in client side.  I want to be able to run a command, it logs in, opens up the window, then runs the command I've set. Ive tried

```
[command] | ssh name@ip

ssh name@ip [command]

ssh name@ip "[command]"

ssh -t name@ip [command]
```

Comment: You want to run a command, and then be left in an interactive shell on the remote server?

Comment: @tripleee according to dates not this but another question is duplicate.

Comment: @zviad The age of a question is a secondary or tertiary concern when marking something as a duplicate. I don't have a strong opinion either way in this particular case, though I feel that perhaps the other question is more likely to be recognized as asking about this particular problem by new users who are looking for a solution to this. Ideally, a site moderator could merge the two questions if they both have valuable answers, though I have never seen that in practice.

Comment: `ssh name@server "command; bash -i"` if you would like to send command to a remote server and stay connected

Answer (score 389, accepted):

```
ssh destination -t 'command; bash -l'
```

will execute the command and then start up a login shell when it completes. For example:

```
ssh -t user@domain.example 'cd /some/path; bash -l'
```

Comment: Forgot my own syntax, almost gave up on this!  For anyone else, just suffix any command with "; bash -l".  Perhaps you could change it to '[command]; bash -l' or something for clarities sake?  I'll change my question.  Thanks!

Comment: I think it's even better to `exec bash -l`.

Comment: That's great, but what if you want the command to show up in the bash history?

Comment: Don't know a good way to push a command into the history.

Comment: Works well but this hides the command prompt for me. Is there are way to make it display in the usual way?

Comment: I get the command prompt when I try it. Check your shell startup scripts to see what they test when setting the prompt, and figure out why it's not being set in this case.

Comment: But what if the script you are attempting to run requires bash environment variables?

Comment: @NobleUplift You could put an explicit `source .bash_profile` before the command

Comment: ssh -i "key.pem" ec2-user@ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
 -t 'sudo su'       but it does not switch to the superuser

Comment: @CEOatApartico Not sure what that has to do with this question, which is about going into a shell after executing some other command.

Comment: For people using Homestead, this worked for me: `homestead.bat ssh -- -t 'cd /home/vagrant/Code/mysite/; ./vendor/bin/phpunit; /bin/bash'` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22529114/470749)

Comment: I normally change the shell to `bash` after loging in. Trying to automate this via above is not working. Any help if it this is achievable? I am trying `ssh $host -t "bash; cd workspace;"

Comment: @mtk https://serverfault.com/questions/368054/run-an-interactive-bash-subshell-with-initial-commands-without-returning-to-the

Comment: Works great. After getting into the login shell I want to kick up a Rails console, something like this: `ssh 123.123.123.123 -t 'cd myapp; bash -l; rails console'`. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Why do you need `bash`? Just `ssh -123.123.123.123 -t 'cd myapp; rails console'`.

Comment: @Barmar I get a Rails error that only shows up when I don't use `bash -l`. The error is `database configuration does not specify adapter`. Maybe it's a bash environment thing. I tried `source .bashrc` but that didn't help. Not sure how to find out what's going on with `bash -l` that makes it work fine.

Comment: Try sourcing your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Jo so's answer is correct. On macOS, the only way I can being an ssh session and then automatically open say, Gnome disks is: `ssh -Y  root@cheese exec gnome-disks`

Answer (score 11):

This isn't *quite* what you're looking for, but I've found it useful in similar circumstances.

I recently added the following to my `$HOME/.bashrc` (something similar should be possible with shells other than bash):

```
if [ -f $HOME/.add-screen-to-history ] ; then
    history -s 'screen -dr'
fi
```

I keep a `screen` session running on one particular machine, and I've had problems with `ssh` connections to that machine being dropped, requiring me to re-run `screen -dr` every time I reconnect.

With that addition, and after creating that (empty) file in my home directory, I automatically have the `screen -dr` command in my history when my shell starts. After reconnecting, I can just type <kbd>Control-P</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> and I'm back in my screen session -- or I can ignore it. It's flexible, but not *quite* automatic, and in your case it's easier than typing `tmux list-sessions`.

You might want to make the `history -s` command unconditional.

This does require updating your `$HOME/.bashrc` on each of the target systems, which might or might not make it unsuitable for your purposes.

Comment: This is quite useful, but what I've noticed is that the history will be cleared, except for the new command on a fresh login. Do you know why that happens and how you can prevent that? I just noticed that after I commented out the line in .bashrc the full history is now available.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `LocalCommand` command-line option if the `PermitLocalCommand` option is enabled:

```
ssh username@hostname -o LocalCommand="tmux list-sessions"
```

For more details about the available options, see the `ssh_config` man page.

Comment: For me, (OS X) this had to be `ssh -o "LocalCommand tmux list-sessions" user@hostname`.

Comment: This answer is based on misunderstanding the question. The question is about running a command on the remote server immediately after connecting. LocalCommand (as the name implies) runs a command on the local machine.

Comment: RemoteCommand is the option you are looking for here. `ssh name@ip -t -o RemoteCommand="tmux ls; bash"`
See: https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#RemoteCommand