# Running remote commands after vagrant ssh

Tags: ssh, vagrant

`vagrant ssh -- EXTRA SSH ARGS` is supposed to allow extra args to be passed to ssh.

`vagrant ssh -- -t 'cd /var/www'` should ssh into vagrant and change directory to `/var/www`, but doesn't. Instead it returns

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname ls: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

What am I missing?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This works for me:

```
vagrant ssh -- -t 'cd /var/www; /bin/bash'
```

Comment: Aha! Brilliant. Start up bash so it doesn't exit immediately. Thank you! You can also do `vagrant ssh -c 'echo hello; /bin/bash'`

Comment: @mpen - it won't work for me with vagrant -c. But this answer works.

Comment: @progonkpa See https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/ssh.html for an explanation on the behaviour of --

Comment: _"If a -- (two hyphens) are found on the command line, any arguments after this are passed directly into the ssh executable. This allows you to pass any arbitrary commands to do things such as reverse tunneling down into the ssh program."_ This is valid with bash in general, not just with Vagrant

Answer (score 20):

To run a command to a vagrant box remotelly run:

```
vagrant ssh -c "COMMAND; COMMAND1"
```

If you need, try `vagrant ssh --help`

Comment: This answer doesn't work in my case, which is executing `vagrant ssh -c "bundle exec rake some_task"`. When the command includes `exec`, it seems fail, and Emyl's answer works fine.

Comment: This allows you to stay on your machine after the command is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but this is still turning up high in Google search results.

Here's another nice way of sending scripts to a remote using a [HEREDOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

If on a Windows host, you'd need to be using a bash emulator like Git Bash or CygWin.

Note the escaped dollar sign, to prevent variables from being interpreted locally.

```
vagrant ssh admin -- -t <<HEREDOC
currentLogin=\$(whoami)
echo "hello \${currentLogin}"
pwd
ls -alZ
HEREDOC

hello vagrant
/home/vagrant
drwx------. vagrant vagrant unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 .
drwxr-xr-x. root    root    system_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 ..
-rw-------. vagrant vagrant unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--. vagrant vagrant unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--. vagrant vagrant unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--. vagrant vagrant unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 .bashrc
drwx------. vagrant vagrant system_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0  .ssh
```