# Continuing shell script execution after SSHing into guest machine?

Tags: bash, shell, virtualbox, git-bash

I have an Ubuntu guest box setup on my Windows host using Vagrant and VirtualBox.  I'm trying to write a shell script that will...

1. `vagrant up`
2. `vagrant ssh` once `vagrant up` is complete
3. `cd` into a specific project directory in the guest machine once successfully SSHed into the guest machine

Right now my vagrant_shell_script.sh file contains the following:

```
vagrant up && vagrant ssh && echo 'cd vagrant/rails_tutorial/sample_app'
```

Everything works fine when I execute it in Git Bash, up to and including connecting via SSH to the guest machine, however after it successfully connects, the script seems to stop working and does not execute the final `cd` command.  I presume this is because it is no longer able to communicate directly with my host machine through that particular Bash instance (please correct me if I'm wrong).

**Is there any way to have it navigate directly to the target directory once the SSH connection is successful?**

Please forgive me if this is a dumb question--relatively new to bash scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This solved it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523134/running-remote-commands-after-vagrant-ssh) It's kind of hacky, but running

`vagrant up && vagrant ssh -- -t 'cd /vagrant/rails_tutorial/sample_app; /bin/bash'` gets you in. For some reason vagrant keeps kicking you out if you don't launch the shell.

`vagrant ssh --` allows you to pass commands into the SSH client. This is vagrant's own utility. The next flag, `-t` is an SSH flag and it allows SSH to execute certain commands before it hands control back to you. You put your command after the `-t` flag, but make sure to end it with `<last command> ; /bin/bash` so that it launches a shell for you and you don't get kicked out.

Comment: Having trouble Googling for documentation on the `--` and `-t` items.  Can you please clarify what those do and what this is actually doing?

Comment: Just tried it and got this error:
`bash: line 0: cd: vagrant/rails-tutorial/sample_app: No such file or directory`

It does `vagrant up` and SSH's in just fine, but chokes at the end still.  Not sure why it is throwing a colon in after `cd`...

Comment: Where exactly in the directory structure are you trying to go? Is vagrant/rails… under the home directory, or do you mean to go to
/vagrant/rails… /... / ?

Comment: updated answer. Let me know if you need more help. try re-running this one, where you prepend the `/` to the directory where you're going, i.e. `cd /vagrant/... `

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that.  Thanks for catching.

If I wanted to add additional commands within the new Vagrant shell that loads, how can I append additional commands then after `cd`ing into a directory if there's more I want to do?

Comment: No problem, just remember to mark the question as answered.

Comment: Not sure if you saw my edit--can you clarify on how to add additional commands beyond the CD command?

Comment: Yup, just keep adding semi-colons or double ampersands and everything should get executed. Finish off with a call to /bin/bash so you don't get kicked out. I just tested it by `cd` ing into /vagrant and then `touch` ing a file in there.
`$ vagrant ssh -- -t 'cd /vagrant/ && touch TEMP; /bin/bash'`

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Heredoc to run the commands after you ssh by using something similar to this in your script:

```
# Use heredoc to send script over ssh
$ssh_cmd << 'END_DOC'

cd <path>
commands

exit
END_DOC

echo $ssh_cmd
```