# Vagrant ssh --command not working

Tags: ssh, vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to pass a simple command to the vagrant machine.

```
vagrant ssh -c "mysql -u root -e'CREATE DATABASE testing';"
```

The db doesn't get created. Instead I just get 'logged in' to the vagrant machine via ssh.

The same thing happens when I run

```
vagrant ssh -c "touch test.txt"
```

I've also tried with:

- single quotes around command
- `--command` instead of shorthand `-c`

**Any ideas what's going on?**

**Edit**

I'm going to distribute my script and it's going to integrate my script with Homestead, so can't really tweak the vagrant configuration.

**Edit**

Since I'm using Homestead the user and pw is different. It should have been

```
vagrant ssh -c "mysql -u homestead -psecret -e'CREATE DATABASE testing;'"
```

not changing the code above to avoid confusion with already submitted answers.

But nonetheless, this does not solve the problem. The same thing is happening as described above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works

```
vagrant ssh -- -t 'touch test.txt'
```

The flag -t creates a pseudo-tty for bash to use. 
Which is a variation on the answer to this question.

[Running remote commands after vagrant ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523134/running-remote-commands-after-vagrant-ssh)

Which is explained in more detail here.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119894/single-command-to-login-to-ssh-and-run-program/119899#119899

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding that command to your bootstrap file and then use

```
vagrant provision
```

.

Example Vargant File

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.memory = 1024
  end

  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", id: "vagrant-root",
      owner: "vagrant",
      group: "www-data",
      mount_options: ["dmode=777,fmode=777"]

end
```

Example bootstrap.sh that creates a postgres database with your command in it. You'll have to make sure you have the right mysql packages installed.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/redis-server

apt-get update

apt-get install -y --force-yes python-software-properties

apt-get install -y --force-yes postgresql postgresql-contrib

apt-get install -y --force-yes redis-server
apt-get install -y --force-yes apache2
apt-get install -y --force-yes php5
apt-get install -y --force-yes php5-imagick
apt-get install -y --force-yes php5-redis
apt-get install -y --force-yes php5-mcrypt
apt-get install -y --force-yes phppgadmin
apt-get install -y --force-yes php5-gd
apt-get install -y --force-yes php5-intl
apt-get install -y --force-yes php5-sqlite
apt-get install -y --force-yes php5-curl
apt-get install -y --force-yes git

if ! [ -L /var/www ]; then
  rm -rf /var/www
  mkdir /var/www
  ln -fs /vagrant /var/www/vagrant-referron-com
    # 
    sed -i "s#DocumentRoot /var/www/html#DocumentRoot /var/www#g" /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

fi
sed -i "s#AllowOverride None#AllowOverride All#g" /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
sed -i "s#AllowOverride None#AllowOverride All#g" /etc/apache2/apache2.conf


# copy the phppgadmin configuration
cp -f /vagrant/development/postgres/phppgadmin /etc/apache2/conf.d/
cp -f /vagrant/development/postgres/phppgadmin.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/
cp -f /vagrant/development/postgres/config.inc.php /etc/phppgadmin/

# create the postgres database and user
sudo -u postgres createdb sometestdatabase
sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "alter user postgres with password 'postgres';"

# calling mysql to create your testing database.
sudo mysql -u root -e 'CREATE DATABASE testing ;' 


# enable server to listen to port 8080
cp -f /vagrant/development/ports.conf /etc/apache2/

# install the other apache modules
a2enmod rewrite
php5enmod mcrypt


apachectl restart
```

Comment: Thanks, for this, but I plan on distributing my script and can't be messing with vagrantfiles. I'm trying to integrate with homestead specifically. Thanks though. Sorry my fault for not specifying

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a semicolon .

vagrant ssh -c "mysql -u root -e'CREATE DATABASE testing;'"

ref: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/cant-create-a-mysql-database-when-sshing-into-vagrant

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't fix the problem

Answer (score -1):

try to directly use ssh instead of vagrant:

```
ssh vagrant -c 'your command'
```

you also probably needs to define vagrant host in your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host vagrant
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  IdentityFile ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
  ForwardAgent yes
```