# Can I set up a 'before hook' on certain SSH hosts?

Tags: ssh

I have several hosts in my `~/.ssh/config` file, *some* of which are on my work network. Before accessing those, I need to authenticate myself on that network by running `kinit`, but I often forget to do that.

Is there a command to run `kinit` in a 'before hook' on those SSH hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have ended up doing is setting up some wrappers around typical workflow.

First, I make sure `./bin` is in my `PATH`.

Then I have a script called `./bin/app-ssh` that runs `kinit` before the `ssh` call I need.

I also have `app-*` in my `~/.gitignore_global` so that it doesn't get caught up in a shared repo, but a case could be made that these scripts are useful to everybody.

I have set up similar scripts in other apps' `bin` directories as well. All I need to do then is run `app-ssh` in whichever app I'm working on, and I don't need to remember any of the setup stuff for each one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's exactly such a thing as a 'before hook', but I can see two hacks that could achieve the a similar effect.

Bash Functions (in some init file like .bashrc, .profile, etc)

```
ssh () 
{ 
    echo "do this before ssh'ing"
    command ssh "$@"
}
```

The other possibility that I can think on would be the ProxyCommand option. In your ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host *
  ProxyCommand sh -c 'kinit >&2 && nc %h %p'
```

Couple of salient points:

- If you're going to do this, I'd recommend replacing the raw kinit, with a script (ensure_kinit.sh perhaps) which checks if running kinit is necessary, and if so running it.
- If you choose the second option, ensure that you redirect stdout to stderr; stdin and stdout should be kept for SSH Protocol network messages.
- The latter method will work for other commands such as git, and scp, which use ssh to communicate, while the former will only work for ssh.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the bash.rc file. It's run everytime you log in.
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/bash/bashrc

Comment: Hmm... but I only want to run it when I'm trying to connect to these hosts, not every time I open a new terminal. Also, I only need to run it every so often, since I remain authenticated on the network for (I think) six hours - but I could set up a script that's like "only run `kinit` if it hasn't been run in the last six hours".

Comment: ssh -t 'command; bash -l'
Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522647/run-ssh-and-immediately-execute-command

Comment: Doesn't that run `command` on the *remote* host, *after* it has successfully connected (but before logging in)? My script needs to run *locally*, *before* attempting to connect.

Comment: Then write a script that first runs kinit and then connects to all ssh servers at once.

Comment: Why the hell would I want to connect to all the servers at once? I want something that will enable me to *forget* about `kinit` because it will remember for me. I want to use `ssh` just the same as I would for any other host.