# How to execute linux commands in a remote machine with shell script

Tags: shell

I have a test server, from which i need to login to two different prod server and execute
top, free -h, ps -ef commands
could some one help me with a shell script

Comment: And where did you got stuck?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run ssh and immediately execute command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522647/run-ssh-and-immediately-execute-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only `ssh` command can do this:

```
$ for ip in 192.168.138.22{1,2,3}; do ssh ${ip} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "free -h"; done
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.8G        782M        5.2G        152M        1.8G        6.4G
Swap:          7.9G          0B        7.9G
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.8G        1.3G        4.1G        169M        2.5G        5.8G
Swap:          7.9G          0B        7.9G
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.8G        563M        5.9G        118M        1.4G        6.6G
Swap:          7.9G          0B        7.9G
```

However, this need to `authenticate ssh-key` with each other. So, we can use [sshpass](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) to pass the `passqord`:

```
$ for ip in 192.168.138.22{1,2,3}; do sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh ${ip} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "free -h"; done
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.8G        782M        5.2G        152M        1.8G        6.4G
Swap:          7.9G          0B        7.9G
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.8G        1.3G        4.1G        169M        2.5G        5.8G
Swap:          7.9G          0B        7.9G
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.8G        563M        5.9G        118M        1.4G        6.6G
Swap:          7.9G          0B        7.9G
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access to your server, you can execute commands remotely on this way:

```
ssh -i <PATH_YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY>remote_username@remote_host "<COMMAND>"
```