# Using SSH with expected user input for picking an environment on the server

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I am working on a script in linux in which i need to SSH to another server.

I am using this syntax ssh user@ip

When doing a manual SSH when we type "ssh user@ip" a few second, a second prompt will show and ask what environment are we choosing ex 1 to 4

(4) - this is the number of the environment i will be choosing.

But when doing ssh user@ip 4 - error received (bash command not found)

[Here is the image on what is the prompt when using ssh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrTjx.png)

Comment: Do you have control over the account/environment on the target machine? If you're *always* going to go to the same environment it might be easier to modify the process you get to see on logging in. It's most likely part of `~/.bash_login`, `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` ...

Comment: Hi @tink Yes I do have access on this. Mind to explain the process on SSH on these said files?

Comment: If you do `ssh user@ip "bash --noprofile"` you might (depending on whether or not they make use of *forced commands*) be able to get a shell without the prompt. You can then check those files whether they invoke anything that would present you with these options; if they do (if any of them does) you should be able to edit it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what happens after you select the environment, its probably something like:

```
echo 4 | ssh user@ip
```

Feed 4 to whatever is prompting for environment, then exit.

If you need to stay connected, then something like

```
echo 4 | ssh -tt user@ip "ksh -l"
```

`ksh -l` could be replaced by some other shell or command like `vi foo.txt` (here when the command exits, the connection closes).

The above is similar to this previous question:
[Run ssh and immediately execute command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522647/run-ssh-and-immediately-execute-command)

Comment: Hello @Anthony C Howe

Thanks for the help. Upon trying the echo 4 | ssh user@ip. It doesn't work on my end.

I will try to elaborate more on what happens.

This is the scenario:

I enter ssh user@ip after pressing enter it will ask a input from the user to pick what environment to enter on the server.

step 1: ssh user@ip
step 2: input what environment (1 to 4)
step3: arrive at the home of that environment

Comment: Sounds likes a custom script used as your initial "shell" to redirect you to an environment. Are the environments using a known unix shell or something else? Not enough info in OP as to environments. Can you explain more about environment and what your objective is?